# How can I pass external file string and get number of occurrence on log Shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

Here Is My Log Format :

```
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:46,004 (pool-2-thread-3) [run:61] - Device 000d6f000f6okec1 rejoined m    
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:52,700 (pool-2-thread-5) [run:108] - Ignoring event after recent join for m:000d6f000f6okec1    
WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [HandlerConnected.java][accept:79] - RHATrustCenterUpdate SN:-117 from netId:10206(0x27de) macAddress:000d6f000f6okec1) Dropping duplicate packet[accept:79]    
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:46,004 (pool-2-thread-3) [run:61] - Device 000d6f00008uiutg rejoined m    
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:52,700 (pool-2-thread-5) [run:108] - Ignoring event after recent join for m:000d6f00008uiutg    
WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [HandlerConnected.java][accept:79] - RHATrustCenterUpdate SN:-117 from netId:10206(0x27de) macAddress:000d6f00008uiutg) Dropping duplicate packet[accept:79]     
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:46,004 (pool-2-thread-3) [run:61] - Device 000d6f0097655g rejoined m    
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:52,700 (pool-2-thread-5) [run:108] - Ignoring event after recent join for m:000d6f0097655g    
WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [HandlerConnected.java][accept:79] - RHATrustCenterUpdate SN:-117 from netId:10206(0x27de) macAddress:000d6f0097655g) Dropping duplicate packet[accept:79]     
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:46,004 (pool-2-thread-3) [run:61] - Device 000d6f909097655g rejoined m    
INFO  2018-09-21T06:57:52,700 (pool-2-thread-5) [run:108] - Ignoring event after recent join for m:000d6f909097655g    
WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) WARN  2018-09-21T06:57:44,988 (EventThread /dev/ttyS1) [HandlerConnected.java][accept:79] - RHATrustCenterUpdate SN:-117 from netId:10206(0x27de) macAddress:000d6f909097655g) Dropping duplicate packet[accept:79]
```

Here Is My command which gives only past one hour log:

```
awk -vDate1=$(date -d'now-1 hour' +%H:%M:%S) -vDate2=$(date -d'now-1 hour' +%d`) '{ if ($3 > Date1 && $2 >= Date2) print $0}' /var/log/syslog
```

**This Is My Input File:**

```
000d6f000f6okec1    
000d6f00008uiutg    
000d6f0097655g    
000d6f909097655g
```

Now I need to pass this input to one by one and get number of occurrence per device for all three value  **rejoined** **Ignoring** **Dropping** and print line by line for per device.

How can we achieve this ?

**Example Output:**

```
{000d6f000f6okec1 : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1
000d6f00008uiutg : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1
000d6f0097655g   : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1
000d6f909097655g : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1 }
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Does your awk command is relevant? Can we just say we have first file with one hour logs and a second file with device id/number/something and we want to find out the number of rejoined attempts, ignored <something?> and dropped <something?> from the first input file ordered by the device id/number/something from the second file? What have you tried so far? Have a look at `sort` and `join`, and `grep` and `sed` linux commands.

Comment: wrt `Here I have stored past one hour log into variable PAST_HOUR_VALUE` - no, the script you posted will not do that. Make sure the input, output, and code you provide are correct.

Comment: **awk** command just gave me past one hour log. Now I am stuck in how can we achieve to get the relevant details on log using device id from input file..

Comment: @Ed Mortan: I have just assigned it to variable. Is there any other way we can achieve this ?

Comment: The command in your script contains syntax errors. Telling us it does something different just obfuscates your question. Also your expected output is not the exact output you want given that input (you don't REALLY want 3 "."s followed by "etc." output, right?) so again you're making this harder than necessary for us to help you. See [ask].

Comment: I have just updated my question can you kindly have a look.

Comment: You don't need (or want) to go through "one by one".  Assuming your input is small (ie, less than 10000 inputs or so, I'm just making up a number--run some tests to see what your hardware supports), just read the log and use the device ids as in index into 3 arrays that count the metrics.

Comment: Can we achieve it with shell script. If so can you kindly help me with some example code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
awk -v date=$(date -d "now -1.0 hours" "+%FT%T,000") '
    (NR==FNR) { devices[$1]; next }
    ($2 > date) { 
       for (i in devices) { 
          if ($0 ~ i) {
             if      ($0 ~ "rejoined") rejoined[i]++
             else if ($0 ~ "Ignoring") ignoring[i]++
             else if ($0 ~ "Dropping") dropping[i]++
          }
       }
    }
    END {
       for (i in devices) {
          print i,": Rejoined:", rejoined[i]+0", Ignoring", ignoring[i]+0", Dropping", dropping[i]+0
       }
    }' inputfile logfile
```

For the above input, with data set to "2018-09-21T06:50:00,000", I obtain the following output:

```
000d6f0097655g : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1
000d6f00008uiutg : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1
000d6f909097655g : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1
000d6f000f6okec1 : Rejoined: 1, Ignoring 1, Dropping 1
```

**After the question has been updated with some formatting:**

```
awk -v date=$(date -d "now -1.0 hours" "+%FT%T,000") '
    (NR==FNR) { devices[$1]; m = length($1) > m ? length($1) : m; next }
    ($2 > date) { 
       for (i in devices) { 
          if ($0 ~ i) {
             if      ($0 ~ "rejoined") rejoined[i]++
             else if ($0 ~ "Ignoring") ignoring[i]++
             else if ($0 ~ "Dropping") dropping[i]++
          }
       }
    }
    END {

       s="{ ";

       for (i in devices) {
          printf s "%-*s : Rejoined: %3d, Ignoring %3d, Dropping %3d", m+2, "\042" i "\042", rejoined[i], ignoring[i], dropping[i]
          s="\n  "
       }
       print " }"
    }' inputfile logfile
```

For the above input, with data set to "2018-09-21T06:50:00,000", I obtain the following output:

```
{ "000d6f0097655g"   : Rejoined:   1, Ignoring   1, Dropping   1
  "000d6f00008uiutg" : Rejoined:   1, Ignoring   1, Dropping   1
  "000d6f909097655g" : Rejoined:   1, Ignoring   1, Dropping   1
  "000d6f000f6okec1" : Rejoined:   1, Ignoring   1, Dropping   1 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181673/discussion-on-answer-by-kvantour-how-can-i-pass-external-file-string-and-get-num).